# How to call derived class function not present in base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

This is the code. If I want to call DerivedFunction1() in CallFunction(), how can I do that?

```
namespace Inheritance_Console
 {

class Base
{

}

class DerivedClass1 : Base
{
    public void DerivedFunction1() // this fucntion is to be called...
    {

    }
}

class DerivedClass2 : Base
{
    public void DerivedFunction2()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base objBase = new DerivedClass1();

        CallFunction(objBase);
    }

    static void CallFunction(Base objBase)
    {
     //......here  

  objBase. //DerivedFunction1 is not accessible here.

    }
}

}
```

This is not an actual implementation, its an interview question.
I don't know what more details to add. Please ask if you think something else is needed here.

Comment: You'd have to cast it.

Comment: Casting is not safe, though.  How do you know that `objBase` is a `DerivedClass1`?

Comment: As an interview question you should ask why they want to do that as it might indicate a flaw in the design.  At least that's what I would expect from an interviewee.

Comment: @juharr I didn't catch that it's an interview question.  These type of technical quizzes that aren't based in good, real design bug the crap out of me.  Anyone that makes a hiring decision based on this type of question is a short-sighted fool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it into a `DerivedClass1`:

```
if (objBase is DerivedClass1) ((DerivedClass1) objBase).DerivedFunction1();
```

Note how I'm checking if it's actually a `DerivedClass1` first to avoid the invalid cast exception.

Comment: I don't know but for some reason I think what the interviewer was expecting was that I cannot create an object of Base class (and instantiate it to DerivedClass1) to call the function from DerivedClass1 there. I will have to create an object  of DerivedClass1 (and instantiate it to DerivedClass1). I think probably this is what he was expecting. Although now that I have tried your code and it works, I really don't know what was expected.